# Can I use 3 kg filament spools in an Ender 6 3D printer?

Tags: filament, creality-ender-6

In order to save some money on a project, I'm considering using 3 kg spools on my Ender 6.
However, I never attempted this before, and could not find a firm stance on the web.

**I know that it is possible to build a filament hanger/holder separately, but is it necessary on the Ender 6?**

For reference, the spool hanger/holder on my Ender 6 extends **9 cm** outwards of the printer.

The filament loaded in the printer (see photo) is a 1 kg white PLA. The dimensions of the filament drawing are for the 3 kg filament to be used.

[image: Dimension of Filament Spool]
[image: Side View of Ender 6, with dimensions, loaded with a 1kg white PLA spool]
[image: Internal Volume of the Printer, showing the spool hanger (black)]
[image: Close-up of the spool hanger, from inside]

Comment: You should add a little more information, first a side view of the printer with the holder (what is the length of the holder to fit a spool) and a spool on the holder (give the diameter of the spool) and also give the dimensions diameter and width of the 3 kg spool. With this information our users can help you if it is going to fit, else you will get answers to put it on a separate holder, but that would not be the point of this question (considering the last sentence). Otherwise this question should be closed, there are lots of separate holders to find.

Comment: I have had a look at the Ender 6 specs and surprisingly they don't *seem to* specify the max. weight supported, so this seems to be a valid question. What does the default support look like? Is the spool mounted vertically or (less likely) horizontally? If horizontally, then the additional weight probably wouldn't matter as much. What are the differences in dimensions of 3kg spool versus a 1kg spool. If the spool is *much* larger, then would it even fit? Have you tried fitting a larger spool already, and if so, what issues could you foresee? Please [edit] and update question with any new info

Comment: Also, do you mean *I know that it is possible **to** build a filament hanger separately*? The "but" seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I'm not particularly concerned about the weight, the dimensions and the location near the filament sensor and the top of the table the printer rests on might be more important.

Comment: I suppose I was just interested in knowing if anyone had successfully used 3kg spools directly on the Ender 6. Just give me a minute, I'm going to edit the question to make it better to be answered, take the necessary photos, as per @0scar suggestion.

Comment: It is indeed not possible. Thanks for everyone that helped with this question; thank you @Greenonline for going into the trouble of looking into the Ender 6 specs.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad the comments helped you realize you could solve the question yourself! And good that you answered it yourself!

Comment: Get a real spool holder, preferably with a rewinder. Using holders where the spool slips on a central axis is begging for a failed print due to tangled filament. The extruder pulls filament, spool overcomes static friction releasing more filament than necessary, wobbles, and the most recent loop of filament gets trapped under an earlier loop. The extruder pulls the filament taut, and your print fails as the extruder can't feed any more. And you end up blaming the filament manufacturer. Been there, suffered through that, never again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While editing this question and analyzing the input the community provided, I've concluded that it is not possible to use a 3 kg filament spool directly on the Ender 6.

The actual answer depends on the filament spool dimensions you are going to work with.

For one thing, the spool hanger has a length of only 9 cm, while the filament spool has a width of 10.2 cm. I don't think it is a good idea to leave the spool hanging loose.

Secondly, the filament spool would hit the filament shortage sensor.

Comment: Many thanks for answering your own question! IMHO this answer shoud be the accepted answer as this answers the actual question at hand! Note that accepting self-answered questions may take up to 48 hours to be able to do this.

Comment: Why can't you use a big spool with a better spool holder than the peg on the side, which isn't that great for little spools anyway. A better spooler is one of the best bang-for-buck upgrades for your printer. Maybe the question should be "can i use on a fully stock ender?"...

Answer (score 1):

I would absolutely make a more sturdy spool holder that is designed for 3KG filament spools. Spools tend to be filled up to the rim these days, so support your spools as good as you can to ensure straight unwinding.

You really don't want to come back to your printer making a terrible grinding noise where the filament has come off the spool sideways or the spool has fallen off the holder.